# Any jQuery template library for my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery Autocomplete control. Upon selecting an item, a grid is shown under the autocomplete.
This grid will be populated with JSON data, using jQuery selectors to select textfields and then setting a value for each textfield.

I can use a hidden div and display it later but I'm looking for template solution.
Any jQuery template library to help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery templates plugin is perfect for this http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

You can easily map the json result from the autocomplete to the template in the select event of the autocomplete plugin.